# How to pass different result to parent form, when 'X' is clicked on child form?

Tags: c#, forms

I've only been using C# for about a week, and I'm new to programming in general.

I have two forms. On the **parent** form, I have two buttons - **Add** and **Edit**. These buttons open up a **child** form that also have two buttons - **Save** and **Cancel**.

When canceled is clicked on the **child** form, I have an indicator variable setup in code to flag as true:

```
//Indicator on child form; setup in properties.
public bool frmCloseInd { get; set; }
```

Indicator is setup on cancel button to set to true on click event:

```
//Cancel Event on child form
private void but_DM_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      frmCloseInd = true;
      Close();
}
```

The frmCloseInd value is passed back to **parent** the form. An IF statement is run to determine which code is run. The problem - when X is clicked, it still runs the same code as if it were being saved. How can I pass a **true** to frmCloseInd, when X is clicked?

I tried doing a close event, but it picks up on Close() in the save and cancel buttons.

Here is the add button click event on the **parent** form:

```
        private void but_DM_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //instance of child form is called
            frmDirectoryManagerAARecord frm = new frmDirectoryManagerAARecord();
            //Setting properties specific to add button
            frm.Text = "Add Contract";
            frm.ShowDialog(this);

            if (frm.frmCloseInd == true)
            {
                //indicates the user canceled out of the userform. No action performed.
            }
            else
            {
                if (frm.frmAnalytic_ID == 0 || frm.frmClient_ID == 0 || frm.frmProject_ID == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Required values were missing. Analytic ID, Client ID and Project ID are required for entry.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(frm.frmAnalytic_ID + " " + frm.frmClient_ID + " " + frm.frmProject_ID + " " + frm.frmDescrip);
                    try
                    {
                        string database = "DB_NAME";
                        string query_insert = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] 
                                            (Analytic_ID,   Master_Client_ID,   Project_ID, Description, Active)
                                            VALUES(" + frm.frmAnalytic_ID + ", " + frm.frmClient_ID + ", " + frm.frmProject_ID + ", '" + frm.frmDescrip + "', 1)";
                        //calling instance of class ContractSearch to use method connectToDatabase
                        ContractSearch con = new ContractSearch();
                        con.connectToDatabase(database, query_insert);
                        //reloads gridview on parent form
                        Reload_gvDirectoryManager();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the code for the SAVE button on the **child** form:

```
private void but_DM_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                frmAnalytic_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Analytic_ID.Text);
                frmClient_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Client_ID.Text);
                frmProject_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Project_ID.Text);
                frmDescrip = tbox_DM_Descrip.Text;
                Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your problem is to set initial value of the `frmCloseInd` property to `true`:

```
// Default value TRUE for this property indicates that by default we mean
// that the form will be closed using Cancel or X button. If user clicks
// Save button then we set this property to FALSE.
public bool frmCloseInd { get; set; } = true;
```

Also we should set appropriate value to this property in `Save` and `Close` event handlers (if you have `FormClose` event handler then you must not change value of the property `frmCloseInd` in it):

```
private void but_DM_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmCloseInd = true;
    Close();
}

private void but_DM_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        frmAnalytic_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Analytic_ID.Text);
        frmClient_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Client_ID.Text);
        frmProject_ID = Convert.ToInt32(tbox_DM_Project_ID.Text);
        frmDescrip = tbox_DM_Descrip.Text;

        frmCloseInd = false;
        Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

---

As a side note I would like to point out that to implement such functionality in WinForms it is better to use [Form.DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=netframework-4.8).